# serviço retornando resultado de um $http

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, angularjs, http

Estou criando um serviço para uma aplicação **AngularJS** onde devo fazer uma consulta a um ws e retornar um valor para uma variável. o meu problema é que quando eu utilizo o `$http` não consigo fazer com que esse valor retorne, se eu usar um `console.log()`... faço assim:

```
app.service('wsService', function($http){
  var callback;
  $http.get('http://www.meudominio.com/ws')
    .success(function (data) {
      callback = data;
    })
    .error(function (d, s) {
      callback = 'error';
    })
  ;
  //retorne o callback
  return callback;
});
```

meu problema é que se eu fizer isso minha função **callback** não retorna o **data** ou o **error** agora se eu der um `console.log(data)` dentro do `.success` ou `.error` ele retorna...

como posso enviar o retorno dessa requisição para a variável externa?

Comment: Mesmo criando uma variável Global ? 
**var Valor;** no ínicio e Valor = data dentro do *callback*. **return Valor**

Comment: experimenta declarar `callback` dentro do `.success` e do `.error`, tipo `var callback = data;`

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu crio uma variável global no início do serviço, ela fica definida ali como `callback` mas mesmo assim o retorno não funciona...

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira tenteifazer como você disse, mas se eu declaro internamente eu estou criando uma nova variável mas com sua abrangência apenas para dentro do ajax... já tinha pensado nisso antes mas não funcionou...

Comment: é que, como o ajax é assíncrono, ele pode causar esse tipo de problema. talvez setar a global `async` como `false` resolva

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira poderia me mostrar um exemplo de onde eu configuro isso no AngularJS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs da uma olhada nessa discussão. a minha sugestão, no final das contas, não é tão simples assim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha solução foi utilizar a função **$q** do Angular dentro do meu serviço. Ela instancia uma variável e define um gatilho para quando houver uma alteração da mesma, assim eu posso pegar e fazer o `$http` com o seu retorno para dentro da minha variável  `var defer = $q.defer()` e, quando houver a alteração dela eu continuar meu código.

(dica do Caio Felipe Pereira )

Comment: Mas o `$http.get` já retorna uma promessa, não?

Comment: sim no **then()** ele retorna, o problema é que o tipo de tratamento que eu fazia dependia de outros status entre os processos que ocorriam por isso precisei do **$q**

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Precisei usar um treco parecido hoje e funcionou direitinho

Answer (score 1):

Aqui eu faço algo parecido com isso:

```
var variavel_global;
app.service('ajax', ['$http', function ($http){
    this.pesquisaCidade = function(q){
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
            return response;
        }, function(error){
            console.info('error: ' + error);
        });
    };
}]);
app.directive('pesquisa', ['ajax', function(ajax){
    return {
        link: function($scope){
            $scope.pesquisa = function (query){
                ajax.pesquisaCidade(query).then(function(resp){
                    console.info(resp);

                    //se quiser setar uma variavel
                    variavel_global = angular.copy(resp);
                });
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

Acho que fica mais organizado e fácil de compreender.

Answer (score 1):

Se é uma informação que você usará no scope global, eu recomendo declarar a variável em scope global, e dentro da função ali atribuir valor à ela:

```
$scope.retorno;
```

e lá na função:

```
$scope.retorno = error;
```

ou

```
$scope.retorno = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mas o próprio já retorna um callback que pode ser retornando de seu serviço.
O exemplo que o Jonatas respondeu [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67565/26703) é uma maneira melhor de se trabalhar.

Quando você executa um $http ele te fornece alguns métodos que são executados após a conclusão do retorno. Dentro de seu controller (ou onde for utilizar o serviço) você irá executar e esperar sua conclusão através do método then().

Exemplo:

```
app.service('api', function($http){
    var api = {};
    api.busca = function(){
        return $http.get('....').then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    };
    return api;
});
```

E no controller:

```
app.controller('testeCtrl', function($scope, api) {
    $scope.resultados = undefined;
    api.busca().then(function(data){
        // executado após a conclusão da execução
        $scope.resultados = data;
    });
});
```

Essa é uma das formas que você pode separar as responsabilidades de cada módulo.

Comment: sim correto, isso se eu estivesse enviando o retorno para um controller. no meu caso estou usando o `$http` dentro de um serviço onde o retorno dele vai para uma segunda função dentro do próprio serviço. Como ajax não é síncrono ele não retornava o que preciso e o serviço dava erro, por isso usei `$q`

Comment: @LeandroLUK mas você precisa que a execução seja de maneira síncrona ou apenas que sejam executados os métodos de maneira encadeadas (um método chamando outro quando concluir o processamento)?

Comment: Eu precisava que o **$http** fosse concluído e com base nos dados que ele me retornar eu fazer o tratamento, portanto preciso de uma solução síncrona. Isso sem contar que o meu resultado eu iria enviar para outra função após o tratamento.

Comment: @LeandroLUK mas você não precisa ser síncrono para efetuar um tratamento após a requisição ser concluída.
O método **then()**, assim como o success() ou error() são executados apenas após o retorno da chamada $http.get(). A partir daí você pode inclusive passar esse callback para outra função

Comment: Eu sei, meu problema é que, após o **then()** eu fazia o uso de outra função que dependia do processo. Já estava utilizando este método. Obrigado pelo empenho amigo